# How to make lists?

Tags: r, list, function, vector, repeat

How can I write a function that receives 2 arguments: a vector=V and a number=X, and returns two lists:
First is a vector which contains all the digits in V that are below or equal to X,
Second is a vector of digits that are above X.
The vectors should not include repeated digits (if a digit repeats itself it should not appear more than once)

Comment: Please attempt to solve the problem on you own before asking for help. If you plan to work with programming in the future you should read this excellent page: [www.whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: An R function can only return one thing. You can return a `list` which contains two `vectors` which sounds like it would be acceptable to you. `return(list(belowx, abovex))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Freebie Friday...

```
fun <- function(x, v)
{
  z <- unique(v)
  list('<=' = z[z<=x], '>' = z[z>x])
}

> set.seed(152)
> X <- 5
> V <- sample(15, 100, TRUE)
> fun(X, V)
# $`<=`
# [1] 4 2 1 3 5
# 
# $`>`
# [1] 15 12 10  9 11  8  7 14 13  6
```